# what does 賃金繰り mean?

Tags: grammar, business-japanese

賃金繰りがこうも厳しくては、プロジェクトから撤退も

（１）やむにやまれない
（２）やむにやまれる
（３）やむをえる
（４）やむをえない

is a question I am facing. Can't seem to find what 賃金繰り means.... also not too sure about any of those answers.

Comment: Are you sure it says [賃金]{ちんぎん}[繰]{ぐ}り, not [資金]{しきん}[繰]{ぐ}り？

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer on the condition that 賃金 is typo for 資金.

- 資金繰｛しきんぐ｝り is defined in Jisho.org as:
  fundraising; financing; cash flow​
- こうも厳しくては、 is parsed and rewritten like こんなに厳しい＋**ては**、*to be in such a severe situation* + ***since*** ...
- プロジェクトから撤退も is プロジェクトからの撤退 + **も**
  ***even** + to withdraw from the project*

Then, 資金繰りがこうも厳しくては、プロジェクトから撤退も (　　　　　) is interpreted as:
*Since the cash flow is in such a severe situation, even to withdraw from the project is* (　　　　　 ).

> (1) **やむにやまれない**: [set phrase] *unavoidable even if you try to avoid*; In other words, it is like やめようとしてもやめられない
>
> (2) **やむにやまれる**: Logically, an antonym of (1), but there isn't such a set phrase in Japanese.
>
> (3) **やむをえる**: Logically, an antonym of (4), but there isn't such a set phrase in Japanese.
>
> (4) **やむをえない**: [set phrase] *inevitable* or *unavoidable*; In other words, it is like 他にどうすることもできない, 仕方がない, しようがない, 残念だがあきらめるしかない, 望ましくはないがしかたがない or そうするしか方法がない

As is written in Seesawscene's answer, the possible answer is (1) or (4).
The difference between (1) and (4) is the degree or nuance of unavoidability.

As for (1), you would try to avoid it, but as for (4), you know you couldn't avoid it, which means it happens inevitably.

Then, the answer is **(4) やむをえない**.

In other words, "～ては/では/れば、.... も（、）やむを得｛え｝ない" is also a set phrase used like in following examples.

#### Examples:

- こんなに乾燥{かんそう}が続｛つづ｝いてい**ては**、断水｛だんすい｝（するの）**も やむをえない**。
- こうも日照｛ひで｝り続｛つづ｝き**では**、断水（するの）**も やむをえない**。
- 梅雨｛つゆ｝時｛どき｝に雨｛あめ｝が降｛ふ｝らなけ**れば**、夏｛なつ｝の断水**も やむをえない**。
- そんなに夫婦｛ふうふ｝喧嘩｛げんか｝ばかりしてい**ては**、離婚｛りこん｝（するの）**も やむをえない**。
- 苦｛くる｝しい現実｛げんじつ｝によっ**ては**、人殺｛ひとごろ｝し**も やむを得｛え｝ない**。

Answer (score 3):

資金繰り＝cash management, financing

*"Since we are facing such difficult financing, we cannot help retiring from the project."*

2 and 3 are just wrong, grammatically. This kind of expressions is only available in the negative form.

1 and 4 both means "cannot help ~ing."

However, in this context, the correct answer is 4 because all the native speakers would choose 4.

Because it sounds natural to their ears.

I cannot explain the grammatical rule, though.

edit) Oops, it was not 資金繰り, but 賃金繰り.

Maybe, 賃金繰り means 資金繰り.
Or 賃金繰り means "management for the payment to their employees," "salary-payment management."